# Popover not showing when the html content got added through innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

This is something that has bothered me a lot and would be thankful if someone could help me.

I want to take the innerHTML from an already existing popover and put it in another div. When I do this, the popover inside the other div is not working.

**This is my head:**

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

**Body:**

```html
<div id="myPopover" class="com">
  <a
    class="arrow"
    tabindex="0"
    role="button"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-trigger="hover"
    title="Title"
    data-content="Content"
    ><img src="https://i.imgur.com/BQpNMZA.jpg"
  /></a>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>

<div id="demo">hej</div>
```

**Script:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById(
    'myPopover'
  ).innerHTML;
}
```

When I press the button the div with the id "demo" is supposed to get the innerHTML from the div with id "myPopover". This seems to work when I open the inspector in firefox, the problem is that the popover is not displayed.

Comment: What will happen to the popover if removing the code that copies the innerHTML?

Comment: @Pengson Nothing. The first popover is displayed. But the popover that is added later (the innerHTML) is not displayed

Comment: Of course, it works as it supposes to be.  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); only trigger the popover which does exist at the moment when it is exected. At that time the button has not been pressure and the second popover does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add this line to `myFunction()`

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Because you are adding the inner html from the `myPopover` div to the DOM, you will need to initialize the popover on the newly created element. Popover will not know about it otherwise.